# VueJs handle Form Submit on Enter press

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a background in Angular. Starting with vue was an okay experience for me until I came across a problem which VueJS developers seem to have shit on and slid under the carpet.
**How can we create a form in which user can press enter from an input field to submit the form**

This was seriously disappointing.

and please if you know the answer be kind enough to post in the Official vue documentation as well.

*Note:
my workaround: I used `v-on:keydown.enter.prevent='loginUser'` on every input field.
is there any way to not use it this way ( on every input field).

Comment: Enter does submit a `<form>` if it contains a `<button>` (because `<button>`'s `type` defaults to `submit` inside `<form>`'s). Vue can be *"seriously disappointing"* for anyone without moderate HTML and JS knowledge. This is clearly pointed out in their [getting started](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started).

Comment: Unfortunately, the transition from Angular to Vue is not as easy as it seems at first glance. Because Vue is quite transparent with what's under the hood, while Angular is notoriously opaque. Angular requires you to know Angular, above all. Vue requires you to know HTML, JS and CSS above all, in that specific order. In other words, Angular has been hiding DOM behavior from you and now you'll need to learn it.

Comment: The editorializing and cursing don't help your cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `button` type as `submit` as well, form gets submitted when `Enter` key is pressed on any input.

No explicit binding is required on `keypress`.

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data() {
        return {
          title: "Vue 2 -Form submission on Enter",
          formInput:{
            fname:'',
            lname:'',
            gender:'male'
          }
        };
      },
      methods:{
      onSubmit(){
        console.log('submitted', this.formInput)
      }
      }
    })
```

```css
.form{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
gap:10px;
max-width:200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app"><h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="form">
    <input v-model="formInput.fname"  @keydown.enter.prevent placeholder="first name"/>
    <input v-model="formInput.lname" placeholder="last name"/>
     <div>
     <input v-model="formInput.gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" type="radio" value="male"/>male
     <input v-model="formInput.gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" type="radio" value="female"/>Female
     </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <pre>{{formInput}}</pre>
    </form>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: `type="submit"` is redundant on a `<button>` in a `<form>`. `<button>Submit</button>` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

I'd urge you to check out [this page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) on the VueJS documentation.

It explains how to set events on certain interactions. For example, you can trigger a function call on pressing the Enter key within an input field by doing this:

```html
<input type="text" @keyup.enter="submit">
```

This will call the `submit()` method when the `Enter` key is pressed and released (keyup). On press, you can use `keydown` instead.'

In fact, the example I've taken is directly from [this section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) in the page I linked above.

EDIT: A pure-HTML way to do this is to set your `input` type as `submit`, which will allow `Enter` to submit the form

Comment: Thanks for the reply in Angular we use this to submit form:

`<form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">`
 button: 
` <button class="button" type="submit">Purchase</button>`
I wanted something like this. Nilesh has given the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your inputs within `<form> ... </form>` tag